# How to make UTF-8 arrow characters appear the same in all browsers?

Tags: html, css, utf-8

How can I get these UTF-8 arrow characters to appear the same in all browsers?

[image]

I've tried both px and pt and also tried the HTML Entity codes (e.g. `&#9664;`) but they arrows are still appearing differently as one can see here:

[image]

Comment: Use an image. Font rendering is never ever going to be 100% identical across different platforms.

Comment: Use the same font or webfont for them

Comment: @deceze I actually had an image which worked, but the task requires a hover effect which changes the arrow to white on mouseover.

Comment: Then you need another white image in addition... :)

Comment: There are no UTF-8 arrows. There are UNICODE arrows. UTF-8 is only a way to encode UNICODE.

Comment: @deceze that's not true that these *radical* differences are just because of font rendering differences, it just depends on the font used and especially if he hasn't specified a specific font either.

Comment: @Esailija I added font-family:arial but no change, is that what you meant?

Comment: @EdwardTanguay I mean use a custom font that is the same for all... look at github... they use font icons but they look the same.

Comment: @Esailija True, you can probably mitigate the differences using a webfont that you control. But it's still not going to look 100% identical. It depends whether you can live with that or not.

Comment: @deceze the 100% is already impossible even on something like a hex color though :P

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom icon font like [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/), they will look the same across platforms as much as is possible and you gain all the benefits like dynamic sizing and color.

Don't use a common font and common symbol if you want exactly the same look.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: I switched from "black pointing triangles" to "black pointing pointers" which solved the cross-browser problem:

### black-pointing triangles (not similiar cross-browser)

```
&#9664; &#9654;
```

◀ ▶

### black-pointing pointers (similiar cross-browser)

```
&#9668; &#9658;
```

◄ ►